# How do I fix this bug: Cant remove object from a list?

Tags: c#, list, unit-testing, object, debugging

I have this really weird bug where I cannot seem to delete an object from a list. I am using an `Injector` class to pass the same object(thus the same list) around into multiple forms. The `Delete()` function is just a generic delete, really nothing special. However in my unit test it keeps failing and I'm unsure why.

*`Injector` class*:

```
    [Serializable]
public class InjectorClass
{
    public OrderAdministration Administration { get; private set; }
    public WareHouse WareHouse { get; private set; } 

    public InjectorClass()
    {
        Administration = new OrderAdministration(this);
        WareHouse= new WareHouse();
    }
}
```

*Constructor of the `WareHouse` class*:

```
public List<Part> Catalogus { get; private set; }
    public  List<Part> PartsInStock { get; private set; }

    public WareHouse()
    {
        PartsInStock = new List<Part>();
        AddStandardStockToCatalogus();
        AddStockPartsToStock();
    }

    private void AddStandardStockToCatalogus()
    {
        Body body1 = new Body("Body7zk", 1, "Ebony", "Blue");
        Body body2 = new Body("SuperXtrem368", 2, "Maple", "Red");
        Neck neck1 = new Neck("Heavy-Slider", 3, "Juniper", true);
        Neck neck2 = new Neck("SlickFingerBoard", 4, "Oak", false);
        Fretboard fretboard1 = new Fretboard("PrettySlamFinger", 5, "Oak", false);
        Fretboard fretboard2 = new Fretboard("GentleToucher", 6, "Ebony", true);
        Pickups pickups1 = new Pickups("TubeScreamers", 7, Pickups.PickupType.P90);
        Pickups pickups2 = new Pickups("BluesBrothers", 8, Pickups.PickupType.Humbucker);
        Bridge bridge1 = new Bridge("MetalGearRipper", 9, false);
        Bridge bridge2 = new Bridge("BridgeOfLove", 10, true);

        Catalogus = new List<Part> { body1, body2, neck1, neck2, fretboard1, fretboard2, pickups1, pickups2, bridge1, bridge2};
    }

    private void AddStockPartsToStock()
    {
        foreach(Part p in Catalogus)
        {
            PartsInStock.Add(p);
        }
    }
```

The `Delete()` function in the same `Warehouse` class:

```
public int GetStock(Part neededPart)
    {
        if(neededPart == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        int numberInStock = 0;
        foreach(Part p in PartsInStock)
        {
            if(p.Id == neededPart.Id)
            {
                numberInStock++;
            }
        }

        return numberInStock;
    }
    public bool AddToStock(Part arrivedPart)
    {
        if(arrivedPart == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        if(FindByName(arrivedPart.Name).Name == arrivedPart.Name)
        {
            PartsInStock.Add(arrivedPart);
            return true;
        }
            

        return false;
    }

    public bool RemovePart(Part usedPart)
    {
        if (GetStock(usedPart) >= 1)
        {
            PartsInStock.Remove(usedPart);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

*The unit test I run*:

```
Neck neck1 = new Neck("Heavy-Slider", 3, "Juniper", true);
        InjectorClass injector = new InjectorClass();
        Assert.AreEqual(10, injector.WareHouse.PartsInStock.Count);
        injector.WareHouse.RemovePart(neck1);
        Assert.AreEqual(9, injector.WareHouse.PartsInStock.Count);
```

The output on both the assert functions is 10

Edit:
I have re-written my search and delete function to the following:

Search function:

```
public Part FindByNameStock(Part neededPart)
    {
        if (neededPart == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        foreach (Part p in PartsInStock)
        {
            if (p.Name == neededPart.Name)
            {
                return p;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Delete function:

```
public bool RemovePart(Part usedPart)
    {
        Part part = FindByNameStock(usedPart);
        if (part != null)
        {
            PartsInStock.Remove(part);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The code now works and the unit test too.

Comment: What happens when you debug this? Do you even reach `PartsInStock.Remove(usedPart);` ? i.e. does `GetStock(usedPart)` return something `>= 1` ? this isn't in a runnable state, so we can't press play here to see what you're seeing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `PartsInStock.Remove(usedPart);` will try to remove the following object

```
new Neck("Heavy-Slider", 3, "Juniper", true);
```

which is not in your list. The reason is that reference type equality is not based on the properties, but on the actual reference. Whenever you run `new` a new reference is created.

```
var neck1 = new Neck("Heavy-Slider", 3, "Juniper", true);
var neck2 = new Neck("Heavy-Slider", 3, "Juniper", true);
Console.WriteLine(neck1 == neck2); //This is false
```

Check the code here for an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7gAWID

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type) for the IEquatable implementation that will make your code work.

Comment: Marked as Best Answer since logic is very well explained, other answers however hold value too.

Answer (score 0):

`GetStock` uses the Id of the part to find it, whereas `PartsInStock.Remove` tries to remove the part by reference - and the reference you have is different to the item in the collection you're trying to remove from.

```
public bool RemovePart(Part usedPart)
{
    if (GetStock(usedPart) >= 1) // item is found here
    {
        PartsInStock.Remove(usedPart); // but usedPart is a different reference - nothing is removed
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two separate objects of `Neck` although having the same ID are different objects and hence the item is never removed.
Moreover, you can return the value of `List.Remove` as it also returns a `bool` if an item was actually removed. So if no item was removed, it returns `false`:

```
public bool RemovePart(Part usedPart) 
=>        GetStock(usedPart) >= 1 ?
            PartsInStock.Remove(usedPart);
            : false;
```

Use `RemoveAll()` to remove the item by ID. `RemoveAll()` returns an `int` representing the number of items removed:

```
public bool RemovePart(Part usedPart)
{
    if (GetStock(usedPart) >= 1)
    {
        PartsInStock.RemoveAll(part => part.Id == usedPart.Id);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also, since your `RemovePart` returns a `bool`. You can add a check to ensure if it was removed.

```
if (injector.WareHouse.RemovePart(neck1)) 
{
    Assert.AreEqual(9, injector.WareHouse.PartsInStock.Count);
}
```

Comment: Would the removePart function not remove all parts with the ID specified by the condition instead of just one?

Comment: @CodeBoy Yes, it would. Usually, IDs must be unique in nature. If they are not unique in your case, how is a part  currently uniquely identified ?

Comment: they are not, theyre purposely the same. This is because they are all, to some extend, the same parts. See it like a online store where they have, say, a hundred toothbrushes which are all exactly the same and most likely have the same productID (since theyre the same).

Comment: @CodeBoy So does it also mean you want to only remove the first occurrence of the product in the list with that ID?

Comment: I have edited my question to show the solution i made for this. What youre saying is indeed what i try to accomplish. If there is no occurance then do nothing ofcourse. :)